# How to trigger an action after setTimeout JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3La2f15w/)**

I'm creating a function named `preLoader()` and I'm using `setTimeout()` cause I want to make it run for one time only.
When the `preloader()` function finish, I want to hide:

```
<div class="loader">
 <h2 id="loading">0%</h2>
 <h3 id="pleaseWait"></h3>
</div>
```

and show:

```
<div class="mainContent"></div>
```

Comment: So you just want to wait a certain time before hiding/showing these element?

Comment: Simply add statements `$("loader").hide();` and `$("mainContent").show();` at the end of the preLoader function.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just change preloader?  Pass a callback into preloader and call that when finished.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/3La2f15w/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using `animate()`, You don't really have to use both `setTimeout` and `setInterval`. Simply hide/unhide content in a `complete` callback of the animation.

```
function preLoader(){
    // animating numbers
    var arrayPleaseWait = ['P','L','E','A','S','E', ' ' , 'W','A','I','T','.','.','.'];
    var searchReturn = '';
    var current = null;
    var wait = $('#pleaseWait');

    $('body').css({
        'backgroundColor':'#E2F7FA'
    });
    $('.mainContent').hide();

    $('#loading').animate({
        someValue: 100
    },{
        duration: 10000,
        easing:'swing',
        step: function() {
            var l = Math.round(Math.round(this.someValue) * (arrayPleaseWait.length-1) / 100) || 0;
            if(current != l){
                searchReturn = searchReturn + arrayPleaseWait[l];
                wait.text(searchReturn + '|');
                current = l;
            }
            $(this).text(Math.round(this.someValue) + '%');
        },
        complete : function(){
            $('.loader').hide();
            $('.mainContent').show();
        }
    });

}

preLoader();
```

[**JSfiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/1cc4unmt/)

Answer (score 1):

this is the HTML code:

```
<div class="loader">
  <h2 id="loading">0%</h2>
  <h3 id="pleaseWait">pleaswait</h3>
</div> 
<div class="mainContent" hidden="true">ok</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var executed = false;
setTimeout(function() {
    if(!executed) {//the same of if(executed == false) 
        var loader = document.getElementsByClassName('loader')[0];
        var mainContent = document.getElementsByClassName('mainContent')[0]
        loader.hidden = "true";//hide the loader
        mainContent.removeAttribute("hidden");//show the mainContent
        executed = true;
    }
}, 1000);
```